# Set colors on matplotlib plot with slider, set_array()

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

I have a `matplotlib` plot with a slider and am interested in setting the colors of the points plotted as the slider gets dragged one way or the other. I know you can set the colors of points with `set_array()` but so far have had luck passing `set_array()` only 1D arrays of floats. When I pass `set_array()` an array of strings corresponding to `matplotlib` colors, I receive the error and traceback below.

Here are some relevant code snippets, with dummy info. for ease of assessment. With the two commented-out lines in `update(val)`, the error below appears. Un-commenting them, so that `set_array()` gets a float, fixes the issue, but then I lose ability to control the colors with any precision. (For instance, changing 'g' to 'c' makes no perceptible difference in the colors.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import matplotlib.colors as c

x = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.20)

plt.ylim([y.min(), y.max()])
plt.xlim([0, 100])

init = 4

scat = ax.scatter(x[:init], y[:init], s=5, c=['k']*init)
ax_slider = plt.axes([0.15, 0.05, 0.65, 0.03])
slider = Slider(ax_slider, 'Day', 0, 100, valinit=init, valfmt="%i")

#  Update function, called upon slider movement

def update(val):
    val = int(val)

    colors_new = np.array(['k']*val, dtype=object)
    colors_new[::2] = 'g'
    colors_new[1::2] = 'm'
    # colors_new = map(lambda x: c.to_rgb(x), colors_new) 
    # colors_new = np.dot(colors_new, [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])
    scat.set_array(colors_new)

    xx = np.vstack((x[:val], y[:val]))
    scat.set_offsets(xx.T)


#  Call update function on slider value change
slider.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 531, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 310, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 12, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 437, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1493, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2635, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 911, in draw
    Collection.draw(self, renderer)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 264, in draw
    self.update_scalarmappable()
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 808, in update_scalarmappable
    self._facecolors = self.to_rgba(self._A, self._alpha)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cm.py", line 274, in to_rgba
    x = self.norm(x)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 943, in __call__
    self.autoscale_None(result)
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 994, in autoscale_None
    self.vmin = A.min()
  File "/Users/johnsmith/PycharmProjects/LawSchoolData/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 5602, in min
    axis=axis, out=out, **kwargs).view(type(self))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'view'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_array()` only works to set the color values when the color is defined by a colormap. You could create a custom `ListedColormap` and set the values numerically.

If you want to set the colors via color values, you can use `set_facecolors()`:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

x = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.20)

plt.ylim([y.min(), y.max()])
plt.xlim([0, 100])

init = 4

scat = ax.scatter(x[:init], y[:init], s=5, c=['k']*init)
ax_slider = plt.axes([0.15, 0.05, 0.65, 0.03])
slider = Slider(ax_slider, 'Day', 0, 100, valinit=init, valfmt="%i")

#  Update function, called upon slider movement
def update(val):
    val = int(val)

    colors_new = np.array(['k']*val, dtype=object)
    colors_new[::2] = 'g'
    colors_new[1::2] = 'm'
    scat.set_facecolors(colors_new)

    xx = np.vstack((x[:val], y[:val]))
    scat.set_offsets(xx.T)

#  Call update function on slider value change
slider.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Here is an example working with a colormap:

```py
colors = ['k', 'g', 'm']
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)
scat = ax.scatter(x[:init], y[:init], s=5, c=np.zeros(init), cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=len(colors)-1)

#....

def update(val):
    val = int(val)

    colors_new = np.zeros(val)
    colors_new[::2] = 1
    colors_new[1::2] = 2
    scat.set_array(colors_new)
    #....
```

Comment: Amazing—thank you! `set_facecolors` does exactly what I want, but I'm glad to have the colormap option, too.